# I'm not able to update the value of arg1 of const Napi::CallbackInfo &info

Tags: javascript, c++, add-on

I'm not able to update property/argument of const Napi::CallbackInfo &info. I'm calling a addon function from typescript, and want addon layer to update the value of arg1. I have added below code, but it doesn't update the value. I don't get any error while running the app.

```
Napi::Number myFunction(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{   
    float deviceGain = 50;
    Napi::Object obj = info[0].As<Napi::Object>();
    Napi::Value newValue = Napi::Number::New(env, deviceGain);
    obj.Set("value", newValue);
    return Napi::Number::New(env, 0);
}

//This is how I'm calling function from typescript
const data = { value: 45 };
myFunction(data.value);
this.logger.information('##### myFunction returns ', `${data.value}`); // this still gives me 45 instead of 50

Application runs without any error but myFunction() doesn't update the value argument 1
```

Comment: My suspicion is that info is a copy of data.value. Thus, when myFunction modifies info, it is modifying the copy and not data.value.